# How to check which IPv6 is being announced in my network on Linux

Tags: linux, home-networking, ipv6

My ISP provides IPv6 connectivity, but they say nothing about prefix length. However, my router must be announcing some prefix to the network for IPv6 configuration to take place.

Is there a command on Linux to check what Router Announcements a computer is receiving?

Comment: Sure you can check the local prefix length; this will however likely not tell you the actual prefix length as delegated to your router. Does your router not have a status web page?

Comment: It has, but doesn't tell me about the IPv6 prefix, sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `rdisc6` (from "ndisc6") to send a Router Solicitation, which will immediately show the advertisements.

  ```
  # rdisc6 -m wlan0
  ```

  (The `-m` option tells rdisc6 to continue waiting after the first RA, just in case there are multiple routers on the subnet.)
- As a general approach, use a packet capture tool such as `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to see the packets that are being received. IPv6 Router Advertisements are just regular packets, not some kind of hidden out-of-band data.

  With all libpcap-based tools, `icmp6[icmp6type] == icmp6-routeradvert` or just `icmp6` alone can be used to filter out unwanted packets. For example:

  ```
  # tcpdump -v -n -i eth0 icmp6
  # tcpdump -v -n -i eth0 "icmp6[icmp6type] == icmp6-routeradvert"
  # termshark -i eth0 -f icmp6
  ```

  Wireshark and tshark also have a "display filter", where `icmpv6.type == 134` does the same (though you can use capture filters as well):

  ```
  # tshark -ni eth0 -f icmp6 -Y "icmpv6.type == 134" -VO icmpv6
  ```

  (The `-V -O icmpv6` options tell tshark to expand the ICMPv6 layer when printing packets.)

Comment: Thank you! The rdisc6 tool is really useful, and I wasn't aware of it.